# How to test two different linux kernel based io shceduler on same input?

Tags: io

I have developed two different I/O schedulers for linux kernel 3.14. Basically my project is to compare both of these algorithms and specify which one gives less head movements and less average seek time than other on same input.

My question is how can I test both of these algorithms on same input.

I am using fedora 20 DE.

Thanks,
momersaleem

Answer (score 0):

You can test both algorithms on the same input by running the same program on both schedulers. There's not much more to it than that. You can't run two IO schedulers simultaneously so you simply need to reboot and choose a different IO scheduler when you want to test the second one.

[How to change the IO scheduler](https://my.vertica.com/docs/6.0.x/HTML/index.htm#16840.htm)

Comment: Sorry, what kind of same program? Any examples please?

Comment: If you're asking how to measure the performance then I suggest you make your question more clear. You didn't ask how to record the metrics, you simply asked how you would "test" each scheduler. As for the program, any program that accesses random files on your hard drive would suffice. As for the metrics, it shouldn't take much research effort to find  a method or program to get you that information.

Comment: I just need to test both on same input. I tried to run same program but dmesg command is showing different requests when I also open the same files for both algorithms. I also restart the system as you suggested. Any more comments please?

Comment: You're not using a virtual machine are you?

Comment: Yes I am using VMware and have Fedora 20 Desktop Edition installed on it.

Comment: What do you mean by `dmesg command is showing different requests`?

Comment: In my code I have a loop which traverse the whole request queue and prints all the block requests (using printk() function) and then use dmesg command on terminal to show all the output generated by printk() function. Could you please also tell me whenever we run a VM, does it is allocated a same memory locations on hard disk or different memory locations?

Comment: You should post the code that is printing the block requests as well as the output you are getting for each scheduler. The thing with IO scheduling on a VM is the performance may be somewhat random. Although the VM has "sectors" and a "disk head", they do not reflect where the actual files or disk head of your host system is. However, as far as I know, opening the same files on both schedulers should produce reads to the same sectors. There are other things in play though, such as caching, that can throw off your results. That is why you need to post all the relevant code and output.